# Add get-parameter to rewrite_rule in .htaccess does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

We are on the way to develop a small router via the `.htaccess file`.
Now we are trying to pass through a get-parameter in a rewrite_rule. The problem is, that the get parameter is not passed through successfully.

For example we have the following url:

```
https://example.com/shop-verifizierung_2c1c759546318feb3177d7d2a023400a.html
```

and the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-verifizierung_(.*).html$ index.php?seite=$1&webshopparameter=verifizierung&code=$2 [L,QSA]
```

That example works fine and the parameters are set correctly but now we have to add an additional get-parameter `token` like that:

```
https://example.com/shop-verifizierung_2c1c759546318feb3177d7d2a023400a.html?token=6TT38831GN100844
```

So we expand the rewrite_rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-verifizierung_(.*).html?token=(.*)$ index.php?seite=$1&webshopparameter=verifizierung&code=$2&token=$3 [L,QSA]
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

But it wont work as expected. We also tried to use {QUERY_STRING} but the result is thesame. Where is the problem here? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Isnt `QSA` working?

Comment: It is not working. The `QSA` attribute is already appended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules. You could use `THE_REQUEST` variable which will be more suitable more your current condition here.

Also please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.*?)-verifizierung_(.*?)\.html\?token=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  index.php?eite=%1&webshopparameter=verifizierung&code=%2&token=%3 [L,QSA]
```